# Solving the matrix equation and finding the matrices inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $E_1 \begin{bmatrix}12\\35\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}48\\35\end{bmatrix}$ Find $E_1$ and $E_1^{-1}$

I set up the equation and saw that $E_1 * A = B$ so I know that:

$E_1 = A^{-1} * B$

where $I_m =$ Identity Matrix

So I attempted to find $A^{-1} = A*I_m = \begin{bmatrix}12&1\\35&0\end{bmatrix}$

After **RREF** I got: $A^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}1&1/12\\0&35\end{bmatrix}$

So then I tried $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&1/12\\0&35\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}48\\35\end{bmatrix}$ but It is saying that I am incorrect? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is $I_m$? Can you write it down in a martix form?

Comment: $E_1$ is not uniquely determined by your equation.  There are infinitely many such matrices.  Is $E_1$ supposed to be an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, $E_1$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. Let, $E = \begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$, thus we want to solve the linear system:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}12\\35 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 48\\35\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus, we have the system of equations:
$\begin{cases}
12a+35b = 48\\
12c+35d = 35
\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases} b = \frac{48-12a}{35}\\[2ex] d = \frac{35-12c}{35}\end{cases}$

We can choose any values for $a,c$ (as long as $ad-bc\neq 0$ ), otherwise $E^{-1}$ will not be defined. Choosing $a = 1, c = 0\implies b=36/35, d = 1.$

So, we have the matrix $E = \begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{36}{35}\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}.$ You can indeed confirm that $\begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{36}{35}\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 12\\35 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 48\\35 \end{bmatrix}.$

Now, since $E$ is $2\times 2$, we can easily find the inverse. If $E = \begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, then the inverse is given by the formula:
$$E^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: $E^1$ is incorrect.

Comment: $E_1$ is not $\begin{bmatrix}1&36/35\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: As @Bye_World stated, there are infinitely many matrices satisfying the condition $E_1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 12\\35 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 48\\35\end{bmatrix}.$ I just provided one of these matrices. If $E_1$ has a special property you should include that in your post.

Comment: $E_1$ has no special property, what I provided is exactly how the question is stated..

Comment: And that is not one of the solutions because it is deeming it incorrect.

Comment: The homework is claiming that $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 4&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ (I have no idea how they come to this)

Comment: They are also claiming that $E_1^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Firstly, check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,36%2F35%7D,+%7B0,+1%7D%7D+*+%7B12,35%7D).

Comment: Makes complete sense to me, why are they marking it incorrect I wonder?

Comment: Secondly,  we can pick arbitrarily any values of $a,c$ as long as $ad - bc \neq 0.$ If we set $a = 4$ and $c = 0,$ then by the formulae that give $b,d$ we have that $b = 0 $ and $d = 1.$ In that case, we get the matrix you just said and $E^{-1}$ follows directly from the formula for the inverse.

Comment: I understand what you';re saying. What I'm saying is that they are marking it incorrect. Wouldn't $E_1^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&36/35\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: In my example, $a = 1, b = 36/35, c = 0, d = 1.$ So, $$E^{-1}  = \frac{1}{1\cdot 1 - 0\cdot 36/35}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1& -36/35 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1& -36/35 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} .$$

Comment: So weird that it thinks it's incorrect!!! Doesn't make any sense!

Comment: I don't know what to say.. Maybe they require some property for $E_1.$ This is only what I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

there are errors:

even in the case defined $EA = B$ does not imply $E = A^{-1}B$,
for  a matrix A ,

the inverse matrix of $A$ (denoted $A^{-1}$)
exists iff the matrix $A$ is a square matrix and $detA \neg 0$.

you say " so I attempted  to find $A^{-1}=A*I_n$" there is no
reason in the text to look for this type of matrix